# Given matrix $A$, a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, a subset of which of is a basis for Nul($A$) spans Col($A$)

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, ${v_1,...,v_n}$ is a basis for $R^n$ and ${v_1,...,v_k}$ a basis for the nullspace of $A$ then ${Av_{k+1},....,Av_n}$ spans Col($A$).

My thoughts for a proof are that the dimension of $A$ is $n$ and dim Nul($A$) = $k$ so Rank($A$) = dim Col($A$) = $n-k$. Since the $v_i$ are linearly independent the result follows.

Comments appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $L: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}: L(v) = Av$. Choose $u \in \text{Im L}$, then there exists $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $u = Lv$. There exists $c_{i} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $v = \sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}v_{i}$. Then $u = Lv = \sum_{i=k+1}^{n}c_{i}Av_{i}$. It follows that $\text{Im L} \subseteq \text{Span}\{v_{k+1} , ..., v_{n}\}$. But by the rank-nullity theorem, the two sets must be equal since they have the same dimension.